# How to decode js timestamp to python timestamp and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, python, time

I am making a request to one of server and getting response like this:

```
result = {"object_type": "window_id", 
          "cctv_times" : ['1655375216687000', '1655375216717000', '1655375216717000', '1655375216775000']}
```

I am not able to understand the time format it is using and if I have to make a post request to that server with the current time, I am unable to convert the python timestamp into that format.

In python, if I convert the current time into a timestamp, it looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

time_now = datetime.now().strftime("%s%f")
```

This gives me results in something like:

```
1655375242179881
```

But in server response, there are already a few zeros at the end even though the time is live from there, what is the format and how to convert python time into that format?

Comment: `1655375216` would be June 16 2022, which seems reasonable. The timestamp is simply in microseconds…? Simply divide by 1000000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that `datetime.now().strftime("%s%f")` is a timestamps measured in microseconds (since `%s` is seconds and `%f` is microseconds).

And `1655375216687000` and `1655375242179881` are the same length, which suggests your source data is also a timestamp measured in microseconds. (The fact that the last three digits are always `000` suggests that it was originally derived from a source with milliseconds precision, but the value is clearly microseconds).

We can use `datetime.fromtimestamp`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp

However this expects a time in seconds, "as returned by `time.time()`"

So we can:

```py
from datetime import datetime

datetime.fromtimestamp(int('1655375216687000') / 1e6)
```

Which returns `datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 16, 11, 26, 56, 687000)`

Comment: I think you already found the way to get that: `datetime.now().strftime("%s%f")` gives a string value in the right format